# Use sigaction() to break infinite loops in C++ without global variables

Tags: c++, linux, loops, signals, daemon

I'm working on a daemon, which listens to keypresses. I'm using the epoll_wait() system call, which blocks a loop, until something happens on the device. Eventhough it's super efficient on resources, it makes breaking out of the main loop a bit difficult. As of right now, I have a working solution using a global variable. However, I want to eliminate the global variable, but haven't found an efficient way to do so. This is my (simplified) code:

```
/* global variables */
volatile sig_atomic_t run;

void sig_handler(int sig) {
    switch (sig) {
        case SIGINT:
            run = 0;
            break;
        case SIGTERM:
            run = 0;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Unknown signal received." << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* signal handling */
    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_handler = sig_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &action, NULL);

    run = 1;

    /* main loop */
    while (run) {
        epoll_wait(epoll_fd, &epoll_ev, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
        /*
         * epoll_wait() unblocks the loop, because an input has been
         * registered. We use read() to check the input.
         */
        process_input(get_input());
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can find the full code over here: https://github.com/tolga9009/sidewinderd. How would you solve it?

Comment: There is nothing else as efficient.  It is appropriate to use a global variable for global state.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I will just leave it as it is right now. I'm still wondering, if there is any "C++ way" to solve this, or another, more elegant way.

Comment: The only change to make it "more C++" would be using `std::atomic<bool>` instead of `sig_atomic_t`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using fork so that the parent continues to listen(accept) for new events , while the child operates on the arrived events.

Comment: Eventhough this is a very interesting idea, it doesn't answer the question. How would you break the parent loop on SIGINT & SIGTERM signals, without using a global variable?

Comment: The fork based design does not necessitate the use of global variable. However, for the logic based on while loop, global variable is a choice. The better design option based on while loop independent of global variable can be by having while(1) over epoll with conditional break/continue in code.